# Python NLP error can anyone explain more to me of why this error is occuring due to inputs i assume but where am i wrong

Tags: python, nlp, nlp-question-answering

This is my code I am able to execute all lines till the model. fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data = (X_test, y_test)). I am just wondering if someone knows why and explain to me in detail I assume that my input variables in the line is the problem that I am having but I dint understand why

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot,Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense,Flatten,Embedding,Activation,Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
import numpy as np
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

df = pd.read_csv('IMDB Dataset.csv')
df.head()

df['sentiment'].value_counts()

text = df['review'].tolist()
text

y = df['sentiment']

token = Tokenizer()
token.fit_on_texts(text)

token

token.word_index

vocab_size = len(token.word_index) + 1
vocab_size

encoded_text = token.texts_to_sequences(text)

encoded_text

max_length = 120
X = pad_sequences(encoded_text, maxlen = max_length , padding ='post')

X.shape

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state = 42,test_size = 0.2,stratify = y)


vec_size = 300

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, vec_size, input_length = max_length))

model.add(Conv1D(64, 8, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(16, activation = 'relu'))

model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

%%time
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
```

from this line
''' model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))'''

```
Epoch 1/5
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnimplementedError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23044\3427946316.py in <module>
      1 '%%time'
----> 2 model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     50   try:
     51     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

UnimplementedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'binary_crossentropy/Cast' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 992, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 711, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 215, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 601, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1905, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 510, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 499, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 406, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 418, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 531, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2914, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2960, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 78, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3185, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3377, in run_ast_nodes
      if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3457, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_23044\3427946316.py", line 2, in <module>
      model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 5, validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Steven\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2165, in binary_crossentropy
      y_true = tf.cast(y_true, y_pred.dtype)
Node: 'binary_crossentropy/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
     [[{{node binary_crossentropy/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_23546]
```

Comment: What error?  Which line?  Show the complete traceback.

Comment: @TimRoberts I showed the traceback any output could give me an idea

Comment: Are you feeding it text data?  I believe that model needs numeric data.